# Postgres 9.2 tuning quide

Tags: database, postgresql, performance, rdbms

Facing an performance issue on Postgres 9.2 on Linux env, Select query on relation ( having 3 to 4 child table) table taking 25 to 35 times more than before migration from other DB. Also I observe CPU utilization of PostgreSQL  service hitting 99% when I run the top command. Recently was facing issue on Delete which was hanging for long duration. Hence introduced indexing on the child table. 
The client been OpenJPA 2.4.

Current setting is on default setting, Any suggestion or key inputs for improving the performance.

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add the `create table` statements for the tables in question, the query that is slow and the execution plan generated using `explain (analyze, verbose)`. [**Formatted text**](http://dba.stackexchange.com/help/formatting) please, [no screen shots](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-may-i-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557)

Comment: https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Slow_Query_Questions

Comment: TY, will go through the link. Am not sure can I paste the DDL of the tables . On top level the index I have created on the foreign key on each child table.   Roughly hierarchy is 5 level. I tried executing EXPLAIN on some select  queries & tried referring https://explain.depesz.com/ , was checking the stats. What I felt is there is an additional time on the index scan.